# Argument list for class template "calc" is missing

Tags: c++, templates, math, floating-point, class-template

I am trying to modify the class “calc” to be more generic to accept also doubles or floats.

```
class calc {
public:
    int multiply(int x, int y);
    int add(int x, int y);
};

int calc::multiply(int k1, int k2)
{
    return k1 * k2;
}

int calc::add(int k1, int k2)
{
    return k1 + k2;
}
```

This is my implementation below, but I have an error E0441: argument list for class template "calc" is missing (line: calc c;).

```
template < class T>
class calc
{
public:

    T multiply(T x, T y);
    T add (T x, T y);
};

template < class T>
T calc<T>::multiply(T k1, T k2)
{
    return k1 * k2;
}

template < class T>
T calc<T>::add(T k1, T k2)
{
    return k1 + k2;
}

int main()
{
    calc c;
    std::cout << c.multiply(1, 5);
}
```

How do I convert the class to be a template class and function?

Comment: `calc c;` --> `calc<int> c;`? Perhaps [a good book on C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) is in order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is the compiler to know what kind of `calc` you want? You have to tell it:

```
calc<int> c;
```

or

```
calc<double> c;
```

or...

Answer (score 1):

[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) is a strongly typed language, meaning that you must fully specify all types at declaration. If `calc` is templated, you cannot declare: `calc c` as that does not fully specify the type. You must provide the template parameter `calc` requires to be fully specified, for example:

```
calc<double> c
```

---

[TonyK's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53520517/2642059) already fully covers this though. I write this to comment that you are reinventing the wheel. The functionality you are writing is already available in the form of:

- [`plus`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus) to do addition
- [`multiplies`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/multiplies) to do multiplication

And these do not require a class. So even if something like: `cout << 1 * 5` did not meet your needs and you needed to enact this in the form of a function call by creating a functor object:

```
multiplies<double> foo;

cout << foo(1, 5);
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/V8OigN)

Comment: That is not what `plus` and `multiplies` are for -- in this context, they are just the same as `+` and `*`. What the OP wants is e.g. a `calc<float>` class that returns a `float` even if both arguments are `int`.

Comment: @TonyK The function definitions I was seeing were: `T multiply(T k1, T k2) { return k1 * k2; }` thus exactly matching the signature of `multiplies`, unless I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: No, they are not the same: `multiplies(3,5)` will return `15`; but `calc<float>::multiply(3,5)` will return `15.0f`. More important, `divides(3,5)` will return `0`; but `calc<float>::divide(3,5)` will return `0.6f`.

Comment: @TonyK Well it's a functor, so in looking at it again due to your comment I did catch that mistake :( But when correctly initialized, it does fully replace `calc`. I've added an example in to demonstrate... and make sure that I did it right :J